# Machine Learning Studio - Experiment stuck in queued

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

When I try to run my experiment I find that I am stuck in queued.

Yes I am on a free account but I am not running two projects at the same time.

I have tried deleting all my projects and creating a new one but this also does not get passed the queued stage.

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get jobs to move from "Queued" to "Running" by manually starting the Compute used by the job.

Answer (score -1):

The maximum execution time for the free tier per experiment is one hour. If your experiment need more than a hour of execution time that'll get queued. 
In the paid version you'll get 7 days (168 hours) for a single experiment execution.